# SOQL Performance : LastModifiedDate vs SystemModStamp

Tags: apex, soql, performance

From [Force.com SOQL Performance Tips: LastModifiedDate vs SystemModStamp](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/11/force-com-soql-performance-tips-systemmodstamp-vs-lastmodifieddate-2.html):

> However, the query optimizer cannot use the index if the SOQL query filter uses LastModifiedDate to determine the upper boundary of a date range because SystemModStamp can be greater (i.e., a later date) than LastModifiedDate. This is to avoid missing records that fall in between the two
>    timestamps.

I do not understand how it can miss records? Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article covers it pretty well.

> - SystemModStamp is strictly read-only. Not only is it updated when a user updates the record, but also when automated system processes update the record. Because of this behavior, it creates a difference in stored value where `LastModifiedDate <= SystemModStamp` but never `LastModifiedDate > SystemModStamp`

The key is:

> `SystemModStamp` **can be greater** (i.e., a later date) than `LastModifiedDate`.

So let's say you have a record with these values:

```
LastModifiedDate = 2016-07-21 12:46:00
SystemModStamp   = 2016-07-21 13:30:00
```

In this case, you have:

> records that fall in between the two timestamps

---

Using the above example, let's say you want to use a query filter like:

```
LastModifiedDate < 2016-07-21T13:00:00Z
```

The filter date is between the two `Datetime` values. If the query optimizer uses `SystemModStamp` as a proxy for `LastModifiedDate`, the record described above will not be found. So the optimizer will not do any indexing because, while it would improve performance, it would cause incomplete results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the explanation given here.

For ex. if we change the filter to as below,

```
LastModifiedDate > 2016-07-21T13:00:00Z
```

If the query optimizer uses SystemModStamp as proxy for lastModifiedDate, the above record will be FOUND but it is NOT correct since LastModifiedDate is still 2016-07-21 12:46:00

How are we then saying that SystemModStamp can be used an index for this use case?